# What is wrong with this list?

Tags: string, list, function, vim, numbers

I have a list with these values:

```
['1', '10', '100.3', '1000.4', '1000.42', '150', '200', '250', '304', '32000', '34']
```

I check if listvalue is `> 100.2 && < 1000.4`
and put the values in a new list.

This is the output:

```
['1000.4', '1000.42', '150', '200', '250', '304', '400']
```

What did I wrong?
Why is 1000.4 and 1000.42 in the list and why is 100.3 not in the list?

Comment: First, I can see by the '1000,4' in the output list that you have retyped rather than copied. This is an error-prone list to retype. Is it possible for you to copy from your code, including the if-statement, and output rather than to retype? I'm willing to bet that an error will become evident when we see the copied list.

Comment: I don't know how to copy the output but there was only one error. The ',' in 1000,4 had to be a dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items in the list look like strings to me, and when you convert from a string to a number you get the integer part only. try `:echo '1000.4' + 0.0` for example.

Use the result of `str2float(item)` to compare against a floating point number.

The reason for this is that float support isn't standard, and you need a standard result for an operation like this or scripts would be incompatible between -float and +float builds.

Comment: Can you please give an example? the Str2float(mylist[i]) did not gave the solution.

Comment: @Remonn:  Try `:echo filter(map(['1', '10', '100.3', '1000.4', '1000.42', '150', '200', '250', '304', '32000', '34'], 'str2float(v:val)'), 'v:val > 100.2 && v:val < 1000.4')`, for instance.